# How to grab textarea element from event without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of the textarea element in my form using plain JavaScript events. I am using Vue.js (I am not using v-model as the form will be dynamically generated so there could be more than 1 for example). I have tried a few different approaches. I can seem to grab everything other than the textarea element

```
console.log(event.target.closest("textarea"));
console.log(event.target.parentNode.closest("textarea"));
console.log(event.target.parentNode.closest("form textarea"));
console.log(event.target.parentNode.closest("form > textarea"));
console.log(event.target.parentNode.closest("textarea > form"));
```

Comment: What triggers the event? What type of event is it? What does the DOM look like? Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You misunderstand what `.closest()` does. It looks for a parent element, not a child. Use `.querySelector()` to search for a descendant that matches a selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` searches for the closest parent element, not a child element. Use that to find the enclosing form.

Then use `.querySelector()` to search for a descendant element starting from there.

```
console.log(event.target.closest("form").querySelector("textarea").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a form to submit the values, you can make use of the `FormData` object to parse all inputs:

```js
const formElement = document.getElementById('form');

formElement.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
 
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  
  console.log(formData.get('textValue'));
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <textarea name="textValue">Lorem ipsum dolor</textarea>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```